# C# Mouse_Event out of sync

Tags: c#

I have a problem.
When I send keystrokes to the application using Sendkeys.SendWait i then change the position of the mouse and send keystrokes again. But when i change position and Send keystrokes, it sends the keys on the last position, not on the current. I think this is probably because the application doesnt wait the mouse_event to be processed. Could you please give me some examples on how to wait until the mouse_event is completed ?

This is the code:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("aaa");
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 70, Cursor.Position.Y + 40);
uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
SendKeys.SendWait("aaa1");
```

Comment: Review the MSDN article for the SendKeys class to see how to modify the .config file of the app so SendKeys uses SendInput() instead of a journaling hook.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx